# What am I not understanding about NSFetchedResultsController and deleting objects from the MOC?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am successfully updating a tableview using a NSFetchedResultsController, and this is what I am doing:

- Loading app the app and calling `- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController` to populate the tableview
- Set `self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil`
- Delete all entities named `<myEntityName>`
- Inserting **one or more entities** into the MOC using `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:<myEntityName>                                                                               inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];`
- Hooking the FetchedResultsController backup: `self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;`
- Then I save the MOC

After all this, the FetchedResultsController method `controllerDidChangeContent:` fires, where I have placed `[self.tableView reloadData]` The table updates, and I'm happy.

**Again, this all works fine.** What has caused my hours of head banging is when I **simply remove** the `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName                                                                               inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];` message, I get the following error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no section at index 3'
```

I know generally what is happening: the MOC is out of step with the FetchedResultsController, and it seems that when others experience this they start pulling out `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` and `configureCell:atIndexPath:` to update the fetchController on a row by row basis.

But my question is: why does the simple removal of the managedObject insertion message cause my otherwise-working code to break?

In my original code I delete mangagedObjects and then insert managedObjects just fine, but when I only delete managedObjects the code breaks.

I don't need each cell to update individually, my current code works fine. How do I make it work?

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm going to guess it's actually the missing call to `reloadData` which is causing the problem. If you replace the insert call with a `reloadData` call what happens?

Comment: I have the insert call in a `NSManagedObject` subclass, so replacing the insert call directly isn't possible (that's why I paraphrased my code), but when comment out the call to the subclass and replace that with `reloadData` I get the following error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'`

Comment: Hmm, going to have to see more code.

Comment: I wish I could, but the code is sprawled over 2 helper classes and a subclassed NSManagedObject. But can you confirm that this sequence *should not* trigger an error: 1. Set `self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil` 2. Add, modify, or delete managedObjects in the MOC. 3. Set `fetchedResultsController.delegate = self`. 4. Save the MOC. 5. `reloadData`. Is that the conventional order?

Comment: I could definitely see it causing problems. What happens is the fetched results controller is only notified of changes in the data if there's a delegate set. So when you unset and set the delegate again it's state would be inconsistent with what's has actually happened. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I wanted to delay the updating of the table until all core data transactions occurred - the live insertion, removal and rearranging of the tableCells is distracting to the user IMO. Others have recommended setting the delegate to nil, perform core data operations, then set the delegate. Worked fine until I implemented the above code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28922/discussion-between-sherman-lo-and-matt-miller)